# C# - How to add and delete multiple controls dynamically on button click

Tags: c#

I am trying to code a survey application which requires text boxes to be added and removed dynamically. I managed to create text boxes dynamically on button click but I'm trying to find out how to removed the text boxes dynamically. Currently the delete functions works well only if I remove text boxes starting from the last. When I try deleting any text boxes in the middle followed by a delete of the last text box, a blank text box is created instead. I'm new to programming and am unsure if this is the best method to use. Also, I would like to find out if it is possible to nest text boxes(allow users to add options to their multi choice questions) to **created** text boxes and retrieve values inside later.

Code behind:

```
public partial class Dynamic_Form : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TotalNumberAdded; ++i)
        {
            AddQuestion(i + 1);
        }
    }
    protected int TotalNumberAdded
    {
        get { return (int)(ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] ?? 0); }
        set { ViewState["TotalNumberAdded"] = value; }
    }


    protected void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TotalNumberAdded++;
        AddQuestion(TotalNumberAdded);
    }

    private void AddQuestion(int controlNumber)
    {
        Panel newquestion = new Panel();
        newquestion.ID = "Panel_" + controlNumber;

        TextBox questionbox = new TextBox();
        questionbox.ID = "Question_" + controlNumber;
        questionbox.Text = "Question";

        Button BtnDelete = new Button();
        BtnDelete.ID = "BtnDelete_" + controlNumber;
        BtnDelete.Text = "Delete"+ controlNumber;
        BtnDelete.Click += delete_Click;

        DropDownList DDLType = new DropDownList();
        DDLType.ID = "DDLType_" + controlNumber;
        DDLType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("TextField", ""));
        DDLType.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Multiple Choice", ""));

        //add controls
        questions.Controls.Add(newquestion);
        newquestion.Controls.Add(questionbox);
        newquestion.Controls.Add(DDLType);
        newquestion.Controls.Add(BtnDelete);
    }

    private void delete_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        Control control = btn.Parent;

        if (questions.Controls.Contains(control))
        {
            questions.Controls.Remove(control);
            control.Dispose();
            TotalNumberAdded--;
            Response.Write("Number of Questions:" + TotalNumberAdded);
        }
    }
}
```

Html file:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h1>Test Form</h1>
        <asp:Button ID="btn_add" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btn_add_Click" />
    </div>
    <div id="questions" runat="server">
    </div>
</form></body>
```

.

Comment: Why you don't do it using in javascript? I am assuming that you are using asp.net web pages, Am I right?

Comment: Yes I am using asp.net. If I were to use javascript how do I go about doing it? I went to look for information and mostly do it with C#. I am required to store the information into an XML document too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Aaron Yong, You can do these scenarios from client side using jQuery or javascript too. I have given below code to achieve what you want from server side.

```
private void delete_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        Control control = btn.Parent;

        if (questions.Controls.Contains(control))
        {
            TotalNumberAdded--;
            questions.Controls.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < TotalNumberAdded; ++i)
            {
                AddQuestion(i + 1);
            }
            Response.Write("Number of Questions:" + TotalNumberAdded);
        }
    }
```

You want to recreate controls again, i have added for loop and removed some code in delete click event, then you will achieve.

Comment: I've tried your method but what I've entered into the text box resets whenever I delete a text box.

Comment: If you want to retain the values which you have entered in text box, then you want to rename your delete button id as well button text from all controls except deleted control then only you can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

As i have given above answer, you can also remove below code from previous answered.

```
questions.Controls.Remove(control);
control.Dispose();
```

You will get exact answer

Comment: No, you don't want to remove. Let it be there, after disposing try to change id of all controls starting from 1 to end. For eg, you have added 5 questions, then all row questions controls id will be started from 1 to 5. Now going to delete 3 question, next what do you want to do means, you want to rename old control ids starting from 1 to 4. If you are doing like this, you can retain the values.